# What is getFormattedOptionValue Vs. getFormatedOptionValue?

Tags: code

Is this just a legacy typo? Or is there something that I'm missing. I just noticed this in the file:

**code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php**

```
public function getFormatedOptionValue($optionValue)
{
    /* @var $helper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Configuration */
    $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');
    $params = array(
        'max_length' => 55,
        'cut_replacer' => ' <a href="#" class="dots" onclick="return false">...</a>'
    );
    return $helper->getFormattedOptionValue($optionValue, $params);
}
```

(Edited two typos in the file path)

Comment: `code/local/Mage/Checkoutt/Block/Cart/Item.Renderer.php` has a few issues here - Checkoutt has two T's, and Item.Renderer.php is not a standard Magento class file.

Comment: ahh, I had that extra t in checkout from a weird night of debugging and item.renderer.php is my typo when pasting the file location. should be a /

Answer (score 1):

The method name you have there does seem like a typo. However, it is just setting some parameters specific to the Cart and calling `getFormattedOptionValue` from the helper class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Configuration`, which seems to be doing the actual formatting.

I should mention I'm looking at the file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php`. As the one you mentioned is in the local codepool.. (assuming those are typos and you meant `code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php`)